# Update failed of file descriptor limit

Tags: linux, debian, asterisk, file-descriptor, ulimit

I have a server with Debian wheezy x64, I have problem with asterisk server "Try increasing max file descriptors with ulimit -n", I try to change the file descriptor limit as follows:

```
# su - asterisk
$ ulimit -Hn
4096
$ ulimit -Sn
1024
$ exit
# vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

I added in the end of the file:

```
....
asterisk        soft    nofile          65535
asterisk        hard    nofile          65535
# End of file
```

And when I try to test:

```
# su - asterisk
$ ulimit -Hn
4096
$ ulimit -Sn
1024
$
```

am I miss somethings? (I rebooted the server but I get the same values)

I used this [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, just I change the configuration in the file /etc/security/limits.conf with following lines:

```
....
*        soft    nofile          65535
*        hard    nofile          65535
# End of file
```